# How to distribute an app?

Tags: app-store, b2b

I developed a small app for a friend of mine who has NO COMPUTER KNOWLEDGE.
I want to distribute this app in official way. Not only like a test app through ad-hoc.

I was searching for a solution and I found out 3 possibilities:

- AppStore
- Enterprice Program
- B2B - Volume Purchase Program

My problem is now, that in a case of:

- AppStore - Apple reject apps which are unique.
- Enterprice Program - to pay 299$ is too much, I did it for her for a free to make her life easier.
- B2B - she doesn't have a business licence. And also to get a business licence, she would have to first register a DUNS Number, enroll the program and for all of this she would have no mood. So that in the end she doesn't want to have this app.

What should I do? Is there some way how to distribute a unique app for a private person?

Thank you very much for your answer.
I appreciate any help.

Iva

Comment: define unique? .... apple does aprove a lot really unique app if they dont infringe their developer agreement

Comment: Just reading through this I have to wonder why Apple would reject 'unique' apps. Would they not be more interesting? Or did you mean too specialised?

Comment: If it's too unique maybe it will be great to make it more universal and help other people as well?

Comment: VPP (volume purchase) is based on Appstore distribution

Comment: Unique means that the informations inside the app are interesting only for her.

Comment: 2.12
Apps that are not very useful, unique, are simply web sites bundled as Apps, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may be rejected